# OS X terminal app with custom tab names?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Is there any way or **free** terminal application that would allow me to have **custom tab names** for each terminal session?

Let's say I am connected to few different servers from my terminal and I want to quickly get the prompt of the ONE I need to work with right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the settings you can save in a Terminal.app configuration file.  <strike>Set the title via the menu item `Shell -> Edit Title` then save the terminal configuration file via the `Shell -> Export Settings...` menu item.  When you re-open that configuration file, the settings will be as you saved them.</strike> [Saving the terminal configuration file, as noted in the comments, does not save the window title]

Save the current terminal settings using the `Shell -> Export Settings...` menu item, then open the the resulting .terminal file in a text editor.  This is a standard Apple Property List file.  Somewhere between the `<dict>` tags, add these lines:

```
<key>CommandString</key>
<string>ssh -2 ssh.host.goes.here</string>
<key>WindowTitle</key>
<string>Title String Goes Here</string>
```

Save the file from the text editor, then double click to open it in Terminal.app.

Comment: Another hint.  If you create the window with the `Shell -> New Remote Command...` menu item, the configuration file will also save the fact that you are connecting to a remote system.

Comment: that's great what about editing tab names? I struggle bit how to quickly and easily one particular window of Terminal if I have 3 terminals open so I thought that tabs could help me

Comment: The `Shell -> Edit Title` menu item will change the names of tabs, too.  The window title will take the name of the active tab.  The one thing I can't figure out is how to save a terminal configuration file with more than one remote connection.  Hopefully that won't be a requirement for you.

Comment: @Peter Murray: I can set the title but when I save the config file the title is not there.So when I double click that .terminal file the title is not set :-(

Comment: You're right -- I edited the answer with instructions on how to add the appropriate values to the terminal PLIST file.  Sorry for sending you down the wrong path to start with.

Comment: @Peter Murray: works really nicely! Thank you for that. Any way I can open terminal window and have three named tabs? I tried to duplicate <dict> tag but it didn't work...

Comment: I, too, tried multiple tags in the plist but couldn't get it to work either.  I also couldn't find any documentation on the acceptable values of a plist file.  Unfortunately, it may not be possible.

Comment: I hope it is possible we just don't know how :-) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use the ANSI escape sequences to set the color-xterm window title: http://howtos.linuxbroker.com/howtoreader.php?file=Xterm-Title.html

More details in a recent thread on the [Canberra Linux Users Group mailing list](http://Lists.samba.org%20slash%20archive/linux/July-2010/028161.html).

Comment: very good answer! Any idea if I can have named tabs in xterm?

Answer (score 0):

so it all can be done using `Window Group` in Terminal application.

One can open few tabs and set title (and other settings) for each tab and then `Save Windows as Group`.

If I choose to run my group on start up of Terminal I still get one extra window ?! So I exported the group and double click that to get one window with three named tabs.

Thank you @Peter Murray

Answer (score 0):

I can set Terminal window and Terminal tab titles using the xtermcontrol package (installed via fink), like so:

```
alias tt='xtermcontrol --title'
```

and then

```
tt foo # in one tab
tt bar # in another tab
```